# Remove stored BlockChain when developing ChainCode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I was using this chaincode development [guide](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/API/SandboxSetup.md) to develop some chaincode and test it.

After killing the peer used to test the chaincode and restarting it the BlockChain did not restart (all the block were still there).

How do I remove the previous BlockChain data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data from the BlockChain is stored in the folder: /var/hyperledger/production/db

Remove its contents to start with a new BlockChain.

Comment: This path not found in version 1.0.0

Comment: this directory is to be found inside the peer docker container. Use "docker ps -a" to find the peer container id, then use the command "docker exec -it containerid /bin/bash" to access it's bash, navigate to /var/hyperledger/production/chaincode and delete unwanted chaincodes.